# Regex and sed - remove everything in a text file but filenames

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to clean a list files text. Here's a sample :

```
15Tlb3Bsn5ec71Os6paEyTpf-5YkTsjwo   CNEWS-2018-12-01_07-00-00h.mp4             bin    1.5 GB     2018-12-03 16:03:00
1irhwA-tcExWXs-ksyOQuEBYL-LDktMQB   franceinfo-2018-12-01_06-30-00h.mp4        bin    949.2 MB   2018-12-03 18:43:10
1UEjtEtU27gMA-Bf7J1rTVhFn9D5z0Rjb   LCI-2018-12-01_06-00-00h.mp4               bin    908.2 MB   2018-12-03 17:30:11
1_ouEY6Ugg8h_XvzjE4j4m751o3eMNxhh   BFMTV-2018-12-01_05-30-00h.mp4             bin    1.2 GB     2018-12-03 14:33:25
1f7JWvb6PM9PRhFimXKc8k81qiTVKwe-e   franceinfo-2018-12-01_04-30-00h.mp4        bin    1.0 GB     2018-12-03 18:43:36
1nKzPZw6tKNzErmWdwbq8f-47DSF4cQbt   BFMTV-2018-12-01_03-30-00h.mp4             bin    1.2 GB     2018-12-03 14:33:03
```

So I think that this expression might work :

```
([A-z])*(-)(\d{4})(-)(\d{2})(-)(\d{2})_(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}h)(\.)(mp4)
```

But I've tried a lot of sed command, like :

```
sed -n -E 's/([A-z])*(-)(\d{4})(-)(\d{2})(-)(\d{2})_(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}h)(\.)(mp4)/\2/p' /media/partage/v2/backupGdriveListOnline.txt
```

And nothing seems to work.

Is it the right command output online the filenames ?

Comment: If the filenames don't have whitespaces in them, you could do `awk '{print $2}' file`.

Comment: $2 for 2=´([A-z])*(-)(\d{4})(-)(\d{2})(-)(\d{2})_(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}h)(\.)(mp4)´ ?

Comment: (Oh ok, just $2)

Comment: @petaire $2 means second column.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` does not support some regex functionalities.
Try `grep`:

```
grep -ioP '([A-Z])*(-)(\d{4})(-)(\d{2})(-)(\d{2})_(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}h)(\.)(mp4)' text
```

Output:

```
CNEWS-2018-12-01_07-00-00h.mp4
franceinfo-2018-12-01_06-30-00h.mp4
LCI-2018-12-01_06-00-00h.mp4
BFMTV-2018-12-01_05-30-00h.mp4
franceinfo-2018-12-01_04-30-00h.mp4
BFMTV-2018-12-01_03-30-00h.mp4
```

Also you have a typo in your regex, `[A-z]` should be `[A-Z]`.
`-i`, `--ignore-case`         ignore case distinctions
`-o`, `--only-matching`       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
`-P`, `--perl-regexp`         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression

I can see you put big efforts to your regex, so I suggested this one.

However, apart from awk's clean `print $2` way, you can use sed to really `clean` other things too:

```
sed -E 's/^[^ \t]*[ \t]+//;s/(\.mp4).*/\1/' text
```

It's to remove everything from line beginning to spaces(include),
and remove everything after `.mp4`

Comment: Is it oversimplification to just use `sed -E 's/^[^ \t]+[ \t]+([^ \t]+).*/\1/'` ?

Comment: Nice ! Thank you everyone !

Comment: @PaulHodges  Might be, if the Filenames contain space then it will fail that way.  Otherwise it's okay.

Comment: True, though I was under the impression spaces were being used as a file delimiter, which would be a bad plan if they have embedded spaces. :)